# Linux Script Not Working Properly

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a script and for some reason it seems to be a skipping a step.

```
[2]) echo "Delete a User"
read -p "What is the user that you would wish to delete?" username
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
read -p "Do you want to delete their home directory also? 1(yes)/2(no)" home
else
echo "That user does not exist"
sleep 3
if [ $home -eq 1 ]; then
userdel -r $username
else
userdel $username
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "$username deleted."
sleep 3
else
echo "$username was not deleted."
sleep 3
fi fi fi
;;
```

It works up to the point I ask if the user want's their home directory deleted or not. If I hit yes or no, it just skips and goes to the menu of the script..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your script looks when indented properly. You can see that after you get the input from user about deleting home directory, everything is under else which will not get executed

```
echo "Delete a User"
read -p "What is the user that you would wish to delete?" username
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Do you want to delete their home directory also? 1(yes)/2(no)" home
else
    echo "That user does not exist"
    sleep 3
    if [ $home -eq 1 ]; then
        userdel -r $username
    else
        userdel $username
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$username deleted."
            sleep 3
        else
            echo "$username was not deleted."
            sleep 3
        fi 
    fi 
fi
```

It should probably look like this

```
echo "Delete a User"
read -p "What is the user that you would wish to delete?" username
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Do you want to delete their home directory also? 1(yes)/2(no)" home
else
    echo "That user does not exist"
    sleep 3
fi
if [ $home -eq 1 ]; then
    userdel -r $username
else
    userdel $username
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username deleted."
        sleep 3
    else
        echo "$username was not deleted."
        sleep 3
    fi 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Indenting your code makes the issue pretty obvious:

```
read -p "What is the user that you would wish to delete?" username
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Do you want to delete their home directory also? 1(yes)/2(no)" home
                                  # <-- 2
else
    echo "That user does not exist"
    sleep 3
    if [ $home -eq 1 ]; then      # <-- 1
        userdel -r $username
    else
        userdel $username
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$username deleted."
            sleep 3
        else
            echo "$username was not deleted."
            sleep 3
        fi
    fi
fi
```

The line that I've marked as `<-- 1`, and all of the lines following it, appear to belong in the location marked `<-- 2` — testing the value of `$home` only makes sense after reading in a value for it.